# Creating a graph with multi-edge

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am using NetworkX to create a multi-edge graph in Python,

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.Graph()
Nodes = [0, 1]
G.add_nodes_from(Nodes)
Edges = [(0,1)]
#Edges  =[(0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2)] 
G.add_edges_from(Edges)

nx.draw(G)
plt.savefig("path.png")
```

For a simple graph , defining `Edges = [(0,1)]` allows me to use `G.add_edges_from`. But, when multiple edges are defined between the nodes 0 and 1 `Edges  =[(0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2)]` I couldn't use `G.add_edges_from` to add edges.

I would like to ask for suggestions on how to create a graph with multi-edges.

Answer (score 2):

Changing `G = nx.Graph()` to `G = nx.MultiGraph()` helps in resolving the error.